# Little o and estimation

Tags: calculus, limits

Say I have a function that is little o of $x$ and $x^2$. Is there a way to tell which one would be the best at estimating my function as $x \rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $x \to 0$, it is **more acurate** to know that
$$
f(x)=o(x^2)
$$ than just knowing that
$$
f(x)=o(x).
$$ If $f(x)=o(x^2)$ then $\displaystyle \frac{f(x)}{x^2} \to 0$, which implies that  $\displaystyle \frac{f(x)}{x} \to 0$, since $\displaystyle\frac{f(x)}{x} =x \times \frac{f(x)}{x^2}$.

Comment: What about the speed of convergence. does x^2 converge to 0 faster and thus a better approximation of f?